# import file to zookeeper in java

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, configuration-management, apache-curator

I am using zookeeper for configuration management for my java microservices. For that I use apache curator and java zookeeper client.

How can I import a configuration file(properties or json) to zookeeper when the microservice initializes?

Comment: how about load the file content and create a node with the data of file.

Comment: Thank you. Each node has a single string value, So how can it represent more then one configuration?

Comment: Please elaborate. Here's what I think:

"do it yourself": put the code in your `init` phase, read the csv/ json, and for each item, do

 `org.apache.curator.framework.CuratorFramework.create().withMode(CreateMode.PERSISTENT).forPath(key, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value).getBytes());`


while key might be the node name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`curator framework`](http://curator.apache.org/) if you wanted to load your config in zookeeper. See the [post](https://sysgears.com/articles/managing-configuration-of-distributed-system-with-apache-zookeeper-2/) about how you may use `curator` framework.

There is a some base code example for `yml` files (for spring config):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.curator.framework.CuratorFramework;
import org.apache.curator.framework.CuratorFrameworkFactory;
import org.apache.curator.retry.BoundedExponentialBackoffRetry;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

@Slf4j
public class LoadConfigsInZoo {
    // base path of your config
    // /CONFIG_PATH/APP_NAME,CONTEXT_NAME
    private static final String BASE_PATH = "/configuration/myApp";
    private static final String ZOO_URL = "localhost:2181";
    private static final String CONFIG_FILE = "bootstrap.yml";
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new LoadConfigsInZoo().loadConfig();
    }

    private void loadConfig() throws IOException {
        BoundedExponentialBackoffRetry retryPolicy =
                new BoundedExponentialBackoffRetry(100, 300, 10);
        Map<String, String> config = flattenInnerProperties("", getContentOfYaml(CONFIG_FILE));

        try (CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.builder()
                .connectString(ZOO_URL)
                .retryPolicy(retryPolicy)
                .build()) {
            client.start();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : config.entrySet()) {
                String path = createPath(BASE_PATH, entry.getKey());
                try {
                    log.info("Try add node with name '{}'", path);
                    client.create()
                            .creatingParentsIfNeeded()
                            .forPath(path, entry.getValue().getBytes());
                    log.info("Node with name '{}' was created", path);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.warn("Unable to create node by path: {}, exception: {}", path, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // need your own implementation for properties/json files
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Map<String, Object> getContentOfYaml(String path) throws IOException {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        try (InputStream in = new ClassPathResource(path).getInputStream()) {
            return yaml.loadAs(in, Map.class);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Map<String, String> getContentOfProperties(String path) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream in = new ClassPathResource(path).getInputStream()) {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(in);
            return (Map) (properties);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Map<String, String> getContentOfJson(String path) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream in = new ClassPathResource(path).getInputStream()) {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(in, HashMap.class);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Map<String, String> flattenInnerProperties(String prefix, Map<String, Object> rootMap) {
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : rootMap.entrySet()) {
            String newPrefix = prefix.isEmpty() ? entry.getKey() : prefix + "." + entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            if (value instanceof Map) {
                result.putAll(flattenInnerProperties(newPrefix, (Map<String, Object>) value));
            } else if (value instanceof List) {
                result.putAll(flattenInnerListInProperties(newPrefix, (List) value));
            } else {
                result.put(newPrefix, String.valueOf(value));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Map<String, String> flattenInnerListInProperties(String prefix, List value) {
        int i = 0;
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (Object v : value) {
            String listKey = prefix + "[" + i + "]";
            if (v instanceof Map) {
                result.putAll(flattenInnerProperties(listKey, (Map) v));
            } else if (v instanceof List) {
                result.putAll(flattenInnerListInProperties(listKey, (List) v));
            } else {
                result.put(listKey, String.valueOf(v));
            }
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String createPath(String basePath, String configName) {
        return basePath + "/" + configName.replaceAll("\\.", "/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where we were using zookeeper as the config server and the configuration was stored in yml format in file. 
Instead of writing code for creating the znode hierarchy dynamically as per yml file, I found a groovy based [tool](http://www.therore.net/java/groovy/2015/05/24/yaml-files-intofrom-zookeeper-with-zookeeperdump.html) which basically does the same.

You need to have groovy installed and run as below

```
zookeeperdump.groovy -s localhost:2181 -c /config/application < dump.yml
```